# amazon Elastic Beanstalk aumentar el client_max_body_size para Nginx

Tags: php, aws, codeigniter-3

Me encuentro con el error "413 Request Entity Too Large" al publicar archivos de más de 1.5 MB. He agregado la carpeta

`.ebextensions/`

en la raíz del proyecto y dentro un archivo de configuración

`.ebextensions/proxy.conf`

dentro del archivo agregue la línea:

`client_max_body_size 50M;`

y me sale el mismo error 413

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea sobre cómo puedo superar el límite?

el entorno esta corriendo en Amazon Linux 2/3.2.1 con php 7.3

Comment: Revisa también las directivas de PHP `upload_max_filesize`, `memory_limit` y `post_max_size`. https://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php

Comment: gracias Xerif con eso ya funciono